# How can I sort a list with different objects that implement the same interface?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, collections, comparable

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
  public Double getSalary();


    @Override
    public Double compareTo(final Employee employee2) {
    }
}
```

Two classes that extends this abstract class:

```
public class Manager {
  public Double getSalary(){}
}

public class Chef{
  public Double getSalary(){}
}
```

I want to sort it so that all the Chef objects in the list are in the front, then after all the Chef objects I want the Manager objects to be sorted in descending order with the highest salary first. In other words, for Chef objects, I only want them to be pushed to the front of the list, nothing else. For the Manager object I want them to be sorted by salary and to be put at the end of the list after the Chef objects.

e.g

```
Manager manager1 = new Manager(40000);
Manager manager2 = new Manager(50000);
Manager manager3 = new Manager(60000);
Chef chef1 = new Chef(25000);
Chef chef2 = new Chef(25500);
Chef chef3 = new Chef(28000);
Chef chef4 = new Chef(29000);
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(manager3);
employees.add(manager1);
employees.add(chef1);
employees.add(chef3);
employees.add(manager2);
employees.add(chef4);
employees.add(chef2);
```

After sorting the elements in the list could be like so:

```
0. chef1 = 25000 // Chef objects pushed to front but not sorted by salary
1. chef3 = 28000
2. chef4 = 29000
3. chef2 = 25500
4. manager3 = 60000 // Manager objects pushed to the back and sorted by salary
5. manager2 = 50000
6. manager1 = 40000
```

My compareTo method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Employee employee2) {
    if (this instanceof Manager|| employee2instanceof Manager) {
        return employee2.getSalary().compareTo(this.getSalary());
    }

    return -1;
}
```

However, this brings the Manager objects to the front. I'm confused on how to work with the Chef object in this compareTo method.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: you can't use compareTo on primitives `[int].compareTo([int])` does not work. Use the [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) wrapper class if you want such functionality.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your input. Just reading up on natural ordering on Comparable vs Comparator. Learning new stuff everyday!

Answer (score 4):

Your case sounds like one where creating a `Comparator` would be more appropriate than implementing `Comparable`: the latter is specifically for modelling a *natural order* of instances of the class.

For instance, `Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`: there is a pretty obvious natural ordering of integers.

Your case sounds much more like a one-off case of how you want to sort them e.g. to present in a particular report.

Additionally, I think it is a code smell when parent classes need to know about their subclasses. There is nothing to stop a new subclass being created; it shouldn't be necessary to update `Employee` to handle that fact.

It is easy to convert from one to the other: instead of adding the `int compare(Employee that)` method to `Employee`, you implement a method in the comparator:

```
class ChefsAndManagersComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
    // The logic from any of the other answers,
    // just replacing "this" references with "employee1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 lists, so you don't have to check for specific subtypes:

```
List<Chef> chefs = new ArrayList<Chef>();
List<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<Manager>();

managers.add(manager3);
managers.add(manager1);
chefs.add(chef1);
chefs.add(chef3);
managers.add(manager2);
chefs.add(chef4);
chefs.add(chef2);

Collections.sort(managers);

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.addAll(chefs);
employess.addAll(managers);
```

---

But if you can't change the way the storage of employees is implemented, you could still iterate over the list of employees, checking for each type and inserting into the specific list. Then, concatenate at the end:

```
...
List<Chef> chefs = new ArrayList<Chef>();
List<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<Manager>();
List<Employee> others = new ArrayList<Employee>();

for(Employee e : employees) {
    if(e instanceof Chef)
        chefs.add(e);
    else if(e instanceof Manager)
        managers.add(e);
    else
        others.add(e);
}

Collections.sort(managers);

List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();
result.addAll(chefs);
result.addAll(managers);
result.addAll(others);
```

`ArrayList::addAll` uses `System::arrayCopy` so it's pretty fast. This is also about the same as using a comparator, but it might be a little more readable. It's really up to preference.

Comment: This is perhaps the simplest solution. But in case for future use, due to whatever business reason or legacy code someone isn't allowed to do the above, then I think the other answers are pretty good on how to sort a list with different kinds of objects in a complex way.

Comment: @JohnathanAu That's ok, I just generally dislike checking type information at runtime. I used a solution like this previously myself, for a similar problem. It was worth suggesting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile, you cannot call compareTo() on the primitive int that getSalary returns... Instead you could use the utility method Long.compare()

```
if (this instanceof Manager || employee2 instanceof Manager) {
    return Long.compare(this.getSalary(), employee2.getSalary());
}
```

Also, given this isn't a "natural search order", I'd express it as a Comparator instead of Comparable..., i.e. external to the Employee class, not embedded in it.

```
Collections.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        if (o1 instanceof Manager && o2 instanceof Chef) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1 instanceof Chef && o2 instanceof Manager) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1 instanceof Chef && o2 instanceof Chef) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Long.compare(o1.getSalary(), o2.getSalary());
        }
    }
});
```

Output

```
Chef 25000
Chef 28000
Chef 29000
Chef 25500
Manager 40000
Manager 50000
Manager 60000
```

Comment: Hi, nice catch. The primitive was just an example, in reality we use a Double. I'll change it accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't quite do what is specified: the chefs shouldn't be sorted by salary.

Comment: For extra brownie points, you can sort the chefs as well, for the challenge. But this is not part of the question and isn't needed in my real code :)

Comment: @JohnathanAu to be honest, *not* sorting the chefs takes more effort.

Comment: @adam What happens if a new Employee subclass (ie Waiter) needs to be integrated into this logic? This solution will lead to "spaghetti code"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom comparator and pass it to the [`Collections.sort(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Once you have the comparator, you can do `Collections.sort(employees, new CustomComparator());`.

*The following is one way of doing this but I don't strongly suggest this practice since it can cause complications at runtime, and even make errors when checking for/against child classes.*

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        if(o1 instanceof Chef && o2 instanceof Manager)
            return -1;

        if(o1 instanceof Manager && o2 instanceof Chef)
            return +1;

        if(o1 instanceof Manager && o2 instanceof Manager) 
            return Double.compare(o1.getSalary(), o2.getSalary());

        return 0;
    }  
}
```

As I write this, I think a better approach could be to use multiple lists to store each of the `Employee` types. This would get around the problem of using a check at runtime.

Alternatively, maybe you can implement some field in the interface that gives a different score for each of the implementing types that can in turn, be used to compare `Employee` objects.

Comment: Note that your comparison of `Manager` salaries doesn't obey the contract of `compare`: you need to return zero if they are equal. The primitive wrapper `.compare` methods are a better choice (e.g. `Integer.compare(o1.getSalary(), o2.getSalary())`).

Comment: Would it not be simpler to do Integer.compare(o1.getSalary(), o2.getSalary()). EDIT: Andy got there before me.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'll make the change. Thanks much!